# How to parse paths in text without trailing slash using regex?

Tags: regex, parsing, trailing-slash

I have a log that includes a lot of paths along with other text. I want to get specific paths from the log without a trailing slash.
How to do it using regex?

For example, the text is:

```
some text /dir1/dir2/ some text
some text /dir1/dir3 some text
```

I'd like to get these matches:

```
/dir1/dir2
/dir1/dir3
```

I've tried different methods using positive lookahead, like:

```
\/dir1[^\s]*(?=\/)
```

But they didn't work.  I would appreciate any support.

Comment: [`\/dir1(\/+[^\/\s]+)*`](https://regex101.com/r/i609NX/1) ?

Comment: @jhnc Please, could you put your answer in the "answer section", so I would point it as the one which solved my problem?

Answer (score 2):

Use

```py
\/dir1(?:\/[^\/\s]+)*
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/fQV12p/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```py
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \/                       '/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  dir1                     'dir1'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \/                       '/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^\/\s]+                 any character except: '\/', whitespace
                             (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )*                       end of grouping
```

Answer (score 1):

Well based on your definition you're looking for anything with a leading slash in a space separated ensemble. So:

```
s = 'some text /dir1/dir2/ some text'

print([x for x in s.split() if x[0] == '/'])
```

Output:

```
/dir1/dir2/
```

This will work whichever string you feed in.

Answer (score -1):

```
\/.*\/\S*
```

`\/` - match forward slash

`.*` - match any character for infinite amount of times

`\/` - match forward slash

`/\S*` - match any non-whitespace character for infinite amount of times

This should work assuming you always have a whitespace after `/dir1/dir2/` or `/dir1/dir2`